# How do I add a powershell script to be run post setup during a windows 10 unattended install?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, unattended-processing

I may be going about this the wrong/more difficult way.  I am open to suggestions.

I am running NTLite v2.3.8.8920 [HOME] (`(c)`  NTlitesoft d.o.o) to create unattended Windows 10 discs. After years of doing unattended discs and realizing the ever expanding size of the disc, (Latest disc was 32.73GB!), I found WinGet, the absolutely amazing repository, and have even gone as far as to create my own installer!

The issue for today is: how do I access WinGet during an unattended installation?  I have compiled a list of applications that I use frequently; most that I have been hard coding to the disc and thus this incredible size; and I would love to be able to run this script post-setup and save the time and space.  Here is my code:

```
#The first batch here is a function I created for notification purposes.  Not sure how to do timed popups in Powershell yet.
#Get Words 
    function GW($myinput){
    $WS = New-Object -ComObject "Wscript.Shell"
    $ws.popup($myinput,3,'TK Installer',64)|SET-CLIPBOARD}
```

SET-CLIPBOARD to offload the popup response code.   Need to find a better output or a way to prevent printing this response.

```
function install-myapps(){
Clear-Host
#Variable to hold the application list
$myapps = (
'Microsoft.PowerShell',
'Microsoft-Windows.Terminal',
'Microsoft.DotNet.SDK.3_1',
'Microsoft.DotNet.SDK.5',
'Microsoft.DotNet.SDK.6',
'Microsoft.MSIXCore',
'Microsoft.msmpisdk',
'Microsoft.ADKPEAddon',
'Microsoft.WebDeploy',
'9N5LW3JBCXKF',
'Nlitesoft.NTLite',
'Libretro.RetroArch',
'Notepad++.Notepad++',
'CodecGuide.K-LiteCodecPack.Full',
'Foxit.FoxitReader',
'7zip.7zip',
'OBSProject.OBSStudio',
'XnSoft.XnConvert',
'XnView.Classic',
'XnSoft.XnViewMP',
'corel.winzip',
'XP8K0J757HHRDW')
#Parser
ForEach-Object($aa in $myapps.Split(',')){
#Notification
GW "Installing  $aa`nPlease wait..."
#Installer
WinGet install $aa --silent --accept-package-agreements --accept-source-agreements --force}
}
```

This code works perfectly in both command line and exe format; the latter using PS2EXE or IExpress.  I just cannot figure out how to instantiate it post-setup from the unattended Win1021H2 side.  Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you add commands to the unattend.xml file.

Comment: @js2010 This is true. The question however was about 'how' and 'where' it needs to be added in said XML so that it would launch post setup.

Comment: I was thinking of something like this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/wsim/add-a-custom-command-to-an-answer-file

Comment: @js2010 That certainly is on the right track but the issues that I ran into with that was the script would load, do nothing, and then disappear.  It's as if the proper dependencies were not set, but I cannot figure out how that is as WinGet aka App Installer comes automatically installed with Windows 10.

Comment: Update: winget is the Windows 10 AppInstaller.  The problem that I am running up against is that I cannot utilize this function during post-setup as I have to 1st log into to the Microsoft Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to figure out the process for this so I worked it around differently.
Below is how I fixed this situation:

````
    # The first section opens and names function and 
    # declares variable $Hopeful applied to the full URI for the application we are installing
        # !Considering using get-input but for now we will just use a replaceable variable!
    # The second section begins the downloading and saving process 
        # Begins by separating the application from the URI assuming the format is as www.domain.com/application.exe
        # Note now that the variable $JustApp will pull the just the last portion of the URI which is the application name
        # Also, we'll make sure that what we're trying to do is possible by checking the extension of the last object
        # Because wget needs 2 things; the URI and a place for the download to go; I am creating a directory to put these
        # downloads in. Thus, $MyDir\$JustApp is now the default file point.
cls
Clear-Host

$MyDir = "d:\TKDI\"
    # Create directory
       if($mydir|Test-Path){
       "My Directory Already Exists!"
       }else{
       md $MyDir -Force
       }
# Section 1
        Function TKDI($Hopeful,$MyArgs){
        $_|select
# Section 2            
    $JustApp = $hopeful -split('/')|select -last 1

    
  
    if($justapp -match "exe")
     { 
        switch($MyArgs)
        {
        inno{$x ='/sp- /silent /forcecloseapplications /restartapplications /norestart'}
        S{$x ='/S'}
        silent{$x ='/silent'}
        quiet{$x ='/quiet'}
        passive{$x ='-passive'}
        default{$x =$myargs}
        un{$x ='-uninstall'}
        $null{$x='/?'}
        }
        cls
        echo "Processing $justapp"
        if(Test-Path $mydir$justapp -PathType Leaf){echo 'File Downloaded Already!'}else{wget -Uri $hopeful -OutFile $MyDir$justapp}
        $noteit = 'Installing  $justapp in 5 seconds...'
        $x=6;while($x-- -ge 1){cls;Write-host  $x;sleep 1}
        start -verb runas -wait -FilePath $mydir$justapp -ArgumentList $x

       }elseif($justapp -match "msi") 
       {
       cls
        echo "You're file will be downloaded and installed!"
        wget -Uri $hopeful -OutFile $MyDir$justapp
        start -wait -Verb runas msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "-i $mydir$justapp /passive /norestart"
            }else{
        
          echo "This URI does not result in an application!"
    
         
     }

       }

tkdi www.example.com/index.exe inno #Installs beautifully```
````